# How can i do the following with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/71b0d516013802a2d67aeb7c2e77ed32?s=48&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1',
  success: function(r, s, x){ 
    var type = x.getResponseHeader("content-type");
    console.log(type); 
  }
});
```

This is the ajax requesti written to get the type of image .How can i do the same with pure javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest + you need to take care of every possible error

Comment: What part exactly do you have doubts about? How to make the request or how to get the header?

Comment: https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/ajax/, https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-vanilla-ajax-without-jquery/

Comment: my doubt is about how to get the header @  Federico klez Culloca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With JavaScript you need to do something like this ::**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400');
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: How can i get the header? @Mr.HK